how to calculate row_number in spark streaming sessionized event
I read a kafka topic with structured streaming with this schema : date, sessionId and few other data
my goal is to determine if a received event is the first one for the same sessionId in the current day
exemple input:
receive at time T
2024-11-25T10:00:00.000 ; session1 

outpout:
date, sessionId; row_number
2024-11-25T10:00:00.000 ; session1 ; 1 ; other data

receive at time T + 15
2024-11-25T10:15:00.000 ; session1 ; 

outpout i want:
date, sessionId and row_number
2024-11-25T10:00:00.000 ; session1 ; 1 ; other data
2024-11-25T10:15:00.000 ; session1 ; 2 ; other data

receive at time T + 30
2024-11-25T10:30:00.000 ; session2

outpout i want:
date, sessionId ,row_number
2024-11-25T10:00:00.000 ; session1 ; 1 ; other data
2024-11-25T10:15:00.000 ; session1 ; 2 ; other data
2024-11-25T10:30:00.000 ; session2 ; 1 ; other data 2

I can achieve it with window function and row number, but Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;
some try:
WindowSpec window = Window.partitionBy(col("sessionId")).orderBy("date");

     spark.read...
     .withColumn("event_number", functions.row_number().over(window));

But I get:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;

I feel like i cant resolve it using window_session but can't use row_number anyway
Dataset<Row> query =
        input
        .groupBy(functions.session_window(col("date"), "15 minutes"), col("sessionLiveIp"))
        .count();

But i dont want a count and can't use row_nmber ...
Maybe mapGroupsWithState can solve my problem too but way more complex ?
Using java and Spark 3.3.1
